# Mac Encryption and Reporting

Tags: security, encryption, apple, disk-encryption, sophos

We have a requirement at my company to support Macs.  The machines need to be encrypted and have some sort of way to check in with a management system to verify the encryption status.  This can be summarized to encryption and reporting.

Filevault, which is included with OSX will encrypt the drive, but does not hava central reporting system.

Sophos Safeguard has a central reporting system.  But we have run into problems encrypting the latest 10.8.5 OS X version.  Sophos support has not offered any solutions.

We have considered Sophos Safeguard as an option or using Filevault with a cron job.  Neither solution is optimal.

What are other companies doing for Mac encryption and reporting?  Is there another third part tool that is more reliable?

Comment: Have you looked into Apple's Open Directory? That has mechamisms to enforce policy and verify compliance...

Comment: I would like to stick with Active Directory.  But I'll take a look at Open Directory

Answer (score 1):

Check into the so-called "golden triangle". You can configure your clients such that they use Active Directory for authentication while using the Apple-specific Open Directory mechanisms for applying and enforcing policy (including FileVault).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I reviewed the documentation for Open Directory.  I could not find any information on the integration with FileVault.  Do the clients report back to Open Directory on the status of their drives?  This is a good doc, just wondering how it integrates http://training.apple.com/pdf/WP_FileVault2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions that can be used to enforce FileVault 2 encryption on Macs and report on their status.

Commercial solutions:

JAMF Software's Casper suite - http://www.jamfsoftware.com/software/casper-suite/automate-apple-tools/full-disk-encryption-with-filevault

McAfee EPO management - https://community.mcafee.com/community/business/data/epoenc/blog/2013/11/01/introducing-announcing-mcafee-management-of-native-encryption-v10

WinMagic SecureDoc for Apple - http://www.winmagic.com/products/full-disk-encryption-for-mac

Open source solutions:

Cauliflower Vest - https://code.google.com/p/cauliflowervest/

Crypt - https://github.com/grahamgilbert/Crypt